# Query'd top 15 faults, need the accumulated downtime from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ignition

I'm currently trying to query up a list of the top 15 occurring faults on a PLC in the warehouse. I've gotten that part down:

```
Select top 15 fault_number, fault_message, count(*) FaultCount
from Faults_Stator
where T_stamp> dateadd(hour, -18, getdate())
Group by Fault_number, Fault_Message
Order by Faultcount desc
```

HOOOWEVER I now need to find out the accumulated downtime of said faults in the top 15 list, information in another column "Fault_duration". How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance, you've all helped me so much already.

```
+--------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+
| Fault Number |                Fault Message                | FaultCount |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+
|          122 | ST10: Part A&B Failed                       |         23 |
|            4 | ST16: Part on Table B                       |         18 |
|            5 | ST7: No Spring Present on Part A            |         15 |
|            6 | ST7: No Spring Present on Part B            |         12 |
|            8 | ST3: No Pin Present B                       |          8 |
|            1 | ST5: No A Housing                           |          5 |
|           71 | ST4: Shuttle Right Not Loaded               |          4 |
|          144 | ST15: Vertical Cylinder did not Retract     |          3 |
|           98 | ST8: Plate Loader Can not Retract           |          3 |
|           72 | ST4: Shuttle Left Not Loaded                |          2 |
|           94 | ST8: Spring Gripper Cylinder did not Extend |          2 |
|           60 | ST8: Plate Loader Can not Retract           |          1 |
|           83 | ST6: No A Spring Present                    |          1 |
|            2 | ST5: No B Housing                           |          1 |
|           51 | ST4: Vertical Cylinder did not Extend       |          1 |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+
```

I know I wouldn't be using the same query, but I'm at a loss at how to do this next step.

Fault duration is a column which dictates how long the fault lasted in ms. I'm trying to have those accumulated next to the corresponding fault. So the first offender would have those 23 individual fault occurrences summed next to it, in another column.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: It's unclear how your `fault_duration` column works without sample data.

Comment: Updated.  Please tell me if I'm missing anything still. Thankyou!

Comment: You said something about accumulated downtime...we would need some details about how you might go about calculating that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the SUM accumulator:

```
Select top 15 fault_number, fault_message, count(*) FaultCount, SUM (Fault_duration) as FaultDuration
from Faults_Stator
where T_stamp> dateadd(hour, -18, getdate())
Group by Fault_number, Fault_Message
Order by Faultcount desc
```

Comment: F. Lins you're my hero. That worked. I'll be sure to give you full credit when the boss' come around. Thanks again.

Comment: hahaha glad to help, just make sure to mark it as resolved ;)